# cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

Tags: python, linux, oracle, database-connection, cx-oracle

I am trying to do a sanity testing of newly installed `Oracle client 12.2 in RHEL 7 linux` from a Python program, but it fails with the above error, not sure what I am missing on there. Please help with this case :

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service 
requested in connect descriptor
```

*my `tnsnames.ora` file under `/home` directory*

> ```
>   FRDLD2D1 =
>   (DESCRIPTION =
>     (ADDRESS_LIST =
>       (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(Host = frdld2d1.de.db.com)(Port = 1825))
>     )
>     (CONNECT_DATA =
>       (SID = FRDLD2D1)
>       )
>    )
> ```

*and my python program goes below*

> ```
> #!/usr/bin/python
> import cx_Oracle
> #connection = cx_Oracle.connect('PNTH_LOGGINGB_OWNER/password')
> connection = cx_Oracle.connect('PNTH_LOGGINGB_OWNER/password@10.245.63.34:1825/orcl')
> cursor = connection.cursor()
> querystring = "select * from BDR_JOB_MASTER_LOG where ROWNUM <= 1;"
> cursor.execute(querystring)
> ```

`frdld2d1.de.db.com` *- IP address :* `10.245.63.34`

Appreciate if any points the glitch on here.

`tnsping` utility is not there to test since it is an instaclient version

`oracle-instantclient12.2-basic-12.2.0.1.0-1.x86_64.rpm`.

But with `SQLPlus`, I am able to connect the database without any issues.

Answer (score 9):

Please use this as your connection string :

```
connection = cx_Oracle.connect('PNTH_LOGGINGB_OWNER', 'hdgf_76trf', 
                                cx_Oracle.makedsn('10.245.63.34',1825,'FRDLD2D1') );
```

*Changing `SID = FRDLD2D1` to `SERVICE_NAME = FRDLD2D1` in your `TNSNAMES.ORA` file may be an alternative.*

Comment: I am getting the same error after changing the code as you suggested. `python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    connection = cx_Oracle.connect('PNTH_LOGGINGB_OWNER/hdgf_76trf@frdld2d1.de.db.com:1825/FRDLD2D1')
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor`

Comment: I have corrected the code like this, #!/usr/bin/python
import cx_Oracle
connection = cx_Oracle.connect('PNTH_LOGGINGB_OWNER/passowrd@FRDLD2D1')
cursor = connection.cursor()
querystring = "select * from BDR_JOB_MASTER_LOG WHERE ROWNUM <=1"
cursor.execute(querystring) but this time I haven't got any error but the response from the code is empty, when I do run the python code. Whereas, I see some output while executing the same query in SQLPLUS.

Comment: but what could be the reason I am not getting the output for the code, should I introduce some print statement like, `print cursor.execute(querystring)`?

Comment: @Vijay try `print cx_Oracle.makedsn('10.245.63.34',1825,'FRDLD2D1')`

Comment: @Vijay by the way `SERVICE_NAME = FRDLD2D1` may be an alternative of `SID = FRDLD2D1` in your `TNSNAMES.ORA` file.

Comment: @Vijay pay attention that whether your `uname` or `password` are case sensitive ..?

Comment: The print statement give the output `(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.245.63.34)(PORT=1825)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=FRDLD2D1)))` does this mean or substantiate that my Python code is correct and successfully getting connected from Python using the module cx_Oracle to Oracle?

Comment: @Vijay yes, seems so, and please look at my last 2 comments just before this one.

Comment: It works either, I have changed the tnsname.ora as suggested by you, and in the code as well like "connection = cx_Oracle.connect('PNTH_LOGGINGB_OWNER','hdgf_76trf',cx_Oracle.makedsn('10.245.63.34',1825,'FRDLD2D1'));" it works as well.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your help, much appreciated. I think I have validated the connectivity between Python and Oracle using the script.

Answer (score 5):

You just make dsn in python without config file (tnsnames.ora)

```
dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn(host='10.245.63.34', port=1825, sid='FRDLD2D1')
con = cx_Oracle.connect(user='PNTH_LOGGINGB_OWNER', password='password', dsn=dsn)
```