# Connection of Python to Oracle through Visual Studio 2017 Error

Tags: python, oracle, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, cx-oracle

I have installed the Visual Studio 2017 Community. I installed (or so I think) the Oracle 32 and 64 bit client and I managed to connect with the Visual Studio to an Oracle database from Tools -> Database Connection -> Oracle.
Now, I have a code in Python that uses the cx_Oracle library to connect to an Oracle database. When I execute it, the connection breaks and I check some blogs, it tells me that it is due to incompatibility of the Oracle client. I installed the Oracle ODAC2018 for Visual Studio.
Now, I do ALT + I to open the interactive console with the following lines (which are the same as I use to connect from the code)

```
import cx_Oracle
db_pass_str = "xxx"
db_usr_str = "yyy"
db_str = "database"
db = cx_Oracle.connect (db_usr_str + "/" + db_pass_str + "@" + db_str)
```

And I manage to make the connection to it. I am using Python 3.7 of 64 bit, my Windows machine is of 64 bit and the database is in a unix server to which I connect without any novelty by any means (sqlplus, sqldeveloper).
A similar code is the one that handles the Python code of the program that I am executing. I no longer see the way to connect. From the Pycharm achievement that the program is executed but by Visual Studio no.
Could someone help me with that?

Comment: perhaps you may refer : [Q47005505](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47005505/cx-oracle-databaseerror-ora-12514-tnslistener-does-not-currently-know-of-serv/47005546#47005546)

Comment: you should go client-less. Install ODAC and connect without client.

Comment: What is the actual "incompatibility" error?  Python cx_Oracle will need one of the 32-or 64-bit Oracle client libraries.  Make sure you have the necessary one first in your PATH.  Use the one that matches your Python 32- or 64-bitness.